# SQL filter one table on every row of another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table, A:

```
|Id|alias  |
------------
|1 |alice  |
|2 |alice  |
|2 |bob    |
|3 |alice  |
|3 |bob    |
|3 |charlie|
```

I have another table, N:

```
|name |
-------
|alice|
|bob  |
```

I am looking for a query to return all of the Ids in the first table with *both* the aliases in the second table.  In this example, I want to see

```
`(2, 3)`
```

I can't use a simple join

```
select Id
  from A
    join N on A.alias = B.name
```

Every record in A has alice, so this query returns 1, which is not what I want.  I am having trouble thinking of a syntax that does this kind of thing.  Suggestions?  I am using TSQL and Sql Server, if it makes a difference.

TIA

Comment: Can you also include the expected outcome?

Comment: Sorry, my expected outcome was kind of hidden in the text.  I called it out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from a join
     n
     on a.alais = n.name
group by id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from n);
```

This assumes that the names in `n` are unique.  If not, you need `count(distinct)` instead of the two `count(*)`s.